# Post DragDrop event in datagridview C#

Tags: .net, winforms, events, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have a main form inside of it i am using datagridview, also i am using the dragdrop event for the datagridview to drop files in my datagrdiview, once i drop the file in the datagridview, another form shows to select what is data the user wants to display and arrange of the data .. etc

when my second form shows i want it to be focused exactly like the effect of this code `child.ShowDialog();` means the user can not click the main form until he finish this form

but if i use the above code in the middle of the DragDrop event, the mouse cursor outside of the main form will have the effect of `DragDropEffects.Copy;` and even the folder i dragged the file from freezes until i close the second form

i understand this happening because of `ShowDialog()` here is my code for the dragdrop events.

```
private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

my question is : Is there any post dragdrop event so once the user release the mouse and i get the file name from the drag drop operation, then i can show form2?.

Here is an image of the cursor outside my application.

[image]

**EDIT:**
According to Jimi comment, the problem solved by using BeginInvoke().
This is the exact code i used

```
this.BeginInvoke((Func<DialogResult>)(() => child.ShowDialog()));
```

Comment: Is there something else happening when the file(s) is/are dropped (other events gets triggered)? -- What happens if you `BeginInvoke()` the code that shows the dialog? -- Are you using C# 4.0 for real? What .Net version?

Comment: Your comment helped me solve the problem, please put it as an answer and i will accept it, see my edit.
yes this program intended for user who use window 7, i use .net framework 4.0, 
i am interested to know if i can solve this problem by some feature in higher editions also. thanks.

Comment: Post whatever code you came up with as an answer yourself. Note that my *suggestion* is meant to find out whether some code is blocking while other events are raised -- You don't need to use .Net Framework 4.0 in Windows 7; you should actually target .Net 4.8 and maybe use C# 7.2 / 7.3 (the latter mostly for its generic constraints and better overload resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jimi comment, the problem solved by using BeginInvoke().
This is the exact code i used

```
this.BeginInvoke((Func<DialogResult>)(() => child.ShowDialog()));
```